# Apparent issues with DataFrame string values

Tags: variables, dataframe, reference, julia

I am not sure if this is an actual problem or if I am just not doing something the correct way, but at the moment it appears a little bizarre to me.

When using DataFrames I came across an issue where if you copy a `DataFrame` to another variable, then any changes made to either of the variables changes both. This goes for the individual columns too. For example:

```julia
julia> x = DataFrame(A = ["pink", "blue", "green"], B = ["yellow", "red", "purple"]);
julia> y = x;
julia> x[x.A .== "blue", :A] = "red";
julia> x
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ B      │
├─────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ pink  │ yellow │
│ 2   │ red   │ red    │
│ 3   │ green │ purple │

julia> y
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ B      │
├─────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ pink  │ yellow │
│ 2   │ red   │ red    │
│ 3   │ green │ purple │
```

A similar thing happens with columns too, so if were to say setup a `DataFrame` like the above but use `B = A` before I incorporate both into a data frame, then if the values in one column is changed, the other is also automatically changed.

This seems odd to me, and maybe it is a feature of other programming languages but I have done the same thing as above in R many times when making a backup of a data table or swapping data between columns, and have never seen this issue. So the question is, is it working as designed and is there a correct way for copying values between data frames?

I am using Julia version 0.7.0 since I originally installed 1.0.0 through the Manjaro repository and had issues with the `Is_windows()` when trying to build Tk.

Comment: There's a great [DataFrames Tutorial](https://github.com/bkamins/Julia-DataFrames-Tutorial) that describes this possible [pitfall](https://github.com/bkamins/Julia-DataFrames-Tutorial/blob/master/12_pitfalls.ipynb).  Knowing when a true copy is made, versus another "pointer" to the same data is important, as you discovered.

Comment: Thank you for this. It didn't come up when I searched for DataFrame help, only the original DataFrames.jl page which didn't seem to answer this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look at the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) -- code is more readable if it's formatted well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `y = x` does not create a new object; it just creates a new reference (or name) for the same `DataFrame`.

You can create a copy by calling `y = copy(x)`. In your case, this still doesn't work, as it only copies the dataframe itself but not the variables in it.

If you want a completely independent new object, you can use `y = deepcopy(x)`. In this case, `y` will have no references to `x`.

See this thread for a more detailed discussion:

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-copy-and-deepcopy/3918/2

Comment: Great! Thank you. I had searched online for this issue with DataFrames before coming on here and couldn't find anything. Coming from an R background this problem puzzled me. You also pre-empted an issue with using copy(), since  I had come back on here to add in a comment after reading and trying the information a previous contributor had left :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! Could you please mark the answer as "accepted" if it has resolved your problem?